# Why is $\rm\:x\to (a+bi)\, x.\,$ the only complex linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, linear-transformations

We said in class that all complex linear maps have the form $\rm\:x\to (a+bi)\, x\,$.

It isn't immediately clear to me why **all** complex linear maps have this form.

What about a transformation such that $x\to \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1& 2 \\ 6 & 5 \end{array} \right] x$ what is wrong with this transformation going from $C $ to $C$?

If I can see $C$ as equivalent to $R^2$ (as claimed in class) surely my map must be ok, what am I brutally misunderstanding?

Comment: It's not linear in the complex sense. By _definition_, a function $f$ from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ which is _linear_ over $\mathbb{C}$ must be such that, for any $c \in \mathbb{C}$, $f(cz) = cf(z)$

Comment: The matrix transforms $C$ to $C^2$. The challenged claim is about transformations from $C$ to $C$.

Comment: Thus, the function you proposed is an $\mathbb{R}$-linear transformation from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$, but not a $\mathbb{C}$-linear transformation from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how you consider $\mathbb C$ to be a vector space.

If $\mathbb C$ is a vector space *over $\mathbb C$* (and scalar multiplication is the ordinary multiplication of complex numbers), then the only linear maps are given by multiplication by a complex constant. This is true whenever a field is considered to be a vector space over itself: if $f$ is a linear function then
$$ f(x) = f(x\cdot 1) = x\cdot f(1) = f(1)x $$
so $f(1)$ *must* be a constant that $f$ multiplies everything by.

On the other hand, if you view $\mathbb C$ as a *real* vector space -- that is, you consider $\mathbb R$ to be the scalar field -- then the conditions for being linear puts *fewer* demands on $f$ because there are fewer scalars that it needs to be compatible with. In that case there are *more* functions that qualify as linear, such as the one you suggest.

In order to prevent such confusion, one sometimes speaks about "$\mathbb C$-linear" or "$\mathbb R$-linear" functions when it is not otherwise clear what the scalar field is.

Comment: Thanks, the next question that comes to mind is why is it more useful or natural to view the linear transformations as $\mathbb C$-linear as opposed to $\mathbb R$-linear?

Comment: Whether it's useful or natural depends on context: whether there's some reason why the only transformations to consider for a particular purpose should be the complex-linear ones.